# Reading realtime output from airodump-ng

Tags: bash, redirect, file-io

When I execute the command airodump-ng mon0 >> output.txt , output.txt is empty. I need to be able to run airodump-ng mon0 and after about 5 seconds stop the command , than have access to its output.  Any thoughts where I should begin to look? I was using bash.

Comment: You can always use iwlist for MAC Names, Essids, etc. And you can grep it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start the command as a background process, sleep 5 seconds, then kill the background process. You may need to redirect a different stream than STDOUT for capturing the output in a file. [This thread](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=80307) mentions STDERR (which would be FD 2). I can't verify this here, but you can check the descriptor number with `strace`. The command should show something like this:

```
$ strace airodump-ng mon0 2>&1 | grep ^write
...
write(2, "...
```

The number in the `write` statement is the file descriptor `airodump-ng` writes to.

The script might look somewhat like this (assuming that STDERR needs to be redirected):

```
#!/bin/bash

{ airodump-ng mon0 2>> output.txt; } &
PID=$!

sleep 5

kill -TERM $PID
cat output.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write the output to a file using the following:

```
airodump-ng [INTERFACE] -w [OUTPUT-PREFIX] --write-interval 30 -o csv
```

This will give you a csv file whose name would be prefixed by `[OUTPUT-PREFIX]`. This file will be updated after every 30 seconds. If you give a prefix like /var/log/test then the file will go in /var/log/ and would look like test-XX.csv

You should then be able to access the output file(s) by any other tool while airodump is running.

Answer (score 1):

By `airodump-ng 1.2 rc4` you should use following command:

```
timeout 5 airodump-ng -w my --output-format csv --write-interval 1   wlan1mon
```

After this command has compeleted you can access it's output by viewing `my-01.csv`. Please not that the output file is in CSV format.

Your command doen't work because `airodump-ng` output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`!!! So following command is corrected version of yours:

```
airodump-ng mon0 &> output.txt
```

The first method is better in parsing the output using other programs/applications.