# How to redirect output of a running process to a file in Linux Shell

Tags: piping, output-redirect

I am trying a bit of experiments with airmon-ng script in Linux. Meanwhile i want to redirect output of a process "airodump-ng mon0" to a file. I can see the instantaneous output on the screen. The feature of this process is that it won't stop execution(actually it is a script to scan for AP and clients, it will keep on scanning) unless we use ctrl+c. 
Whenever i try

```
    airodump-ng mon0 > file.txt
```

i won't get the output in the file.
My primary assumption is that the shell will write it to the file only after completing the execution. But in the above case i stopped the execution(as the execution won't complete).

So to generalize i can't pipe the output of a running process to a file. How can i do that?
Or is there any alternative way to stop the execution of the process(for example after 5 seconds) and redirect the current output to a file?

Comment: did you check if you still see the output on the terminal? if you do, then you're not capturing it. it might be that the program actually prints to stderr and not stdout, then you'd have to do `2>file.txt` instead. And redirection should work more or less immediately as far as I know (no need to wait until program has finished)

Comment: what shell are you using? bash? zsh? tcsh? csh?

Comment: Found this which maybe of assistance [realtime reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776383/reading-realtime-output-from-airodump-ng)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process may send output to standard output or standard error to get it to the terminal. Generally, the former is for information and the latter for errors, but in some cases, a process may mix them up.

I'm supposing that in your case, the standard error is being used. To get both of these to the output file, you can use:

```
airmon-ng mon0 > file.txt 2>&1
```

This says to send standard output to `file.txt` and to reroute `2` (which is the file id for standard error) into `1` (the file id for standard output) so that it also goes to the file.

Comment: How can i overwrite the file instead of appending?

Comment: @DDR the `>` in the above should overwrite the file. An append would be `>>`.

Comment: But i get an appended file. When it scans at every instant,i get the result of each scan appended to the file.

Comment: If the data is all occurring on the same "run" of `airmon-ng mon0` then it will all be appended. It will overwrite when the above command completes or is canceled, and then restarted. If you need internal iterations of `airmon-ng mon0` to overwrite the file, then that would need to be done inside that command or script.